# Is there a way to round doubles in JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays, json, dictionary, rounding

I Have a JSON text format. So I put it into object first then to the Map, which has another map in the values (JSON has inner and outer map type in their text format). In the inner map printing a JSONDouble with two decimals isn't a problem (I can just use `printf("%.2f"))` but when JSONArray appears I can't do that.

I have tried `printf` function but it doesn't work.

If it's possible don't use streams.

here is the code:

```java
package doplomski.rad.glavna;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Glavna {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("API url"))
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "website url")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "key")
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = null;

        try {
            response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(response.body());
        System.out.println();

        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(response.body());

        Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> output = (Map) obj;

        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("ac_annual"));
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("solrad_annual"));
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("capacity_factor"));
        System.out.println(output.get("outputs").get("ac_monthly"));
        System.out.println(output.get("outputs").get("dc_monthly"));
        System.out.println(output.get("outputs").get("poa_monthly"));
        System.out.println(output.get("outputs").get("solrad_monthly"));

    }
```

and output:

```
{"inputs":{"azimuth":"180","system_capacity":"4","losses":"14","array_type":"1","module_type":"0","gcr":"0.4","dc_ac_ratio":"1.2","inv_eff":"96.0","radius":"0","dataset":"nsrdb","tilt":"10","address":"boulder, co","soiling":[12.0,4.0,45.0,23.0,9.0,99.0,67.0,12.54,54.0,9.0,0.0,7.6],"albedo":"0.3","bifaciality":"0.7"},"errors":[],"warnings":[],"version":"8.2.1","ssc_info":{"version":280,"build":"Linux 64 bit GNU/C++ Oct 18 2023 07:13:03","module":"pvwattsv8"},"station_info":{"lat":40.0099983215332,"lon":-105.2600021362305,"elev":1635.640014648438,"tz":-7.0,"location":"149190","city":"","state":"Colorado","country":"United States","solar_resource_file":"149190.csv","distance":1750,"weather_data_source":"NSRDB PSM V3 GOES tmy-2020 3.2.0"},"outputs":{"ac_monthly":[350.4450331552693,436.3879540968705,340.7495159069064,442.1920779147474,534.4142671193669,19.89441005557222,206.6577352851099,492.4427511771748,241.7735300594523,382.6085934358003,376.0863140563925,306.6293313390505],"poa_monthly":[104.9805590746965,131.3527386112043,104.2011355720695,138.6804496432297,177.348356252559,9.001239090243104,70.67352420990476,166.9411671806375,79.89308311196012,122.4161912004151,115.6650356864296,91.94797329425062],"solrad_monthly":[3.386469647570856,4.69116923611444,3.361326953937725,4.622681654774324,5.720914717824484,0.3000413030081034,2.279791103545315,5.385198941310887,2.663102770398671,3.948909393561777,3.855501189547655,2.966063654653246],"dc_monthly":[368.0682926594546,457.2045927636358,359.1841462238203,464.7078109487218,561.0990701509306,27.17952816676697,221.2817047541209,517.4117655437504,256.4903025712858,402.0961281476057,394.804951938705,322.3432439889111],"ac_annual":4130.281513601723,"solrad_annual":3.598430880520624,"capacity_factor":11.78733308676288}}

4130,28
3,60
11,79
[350.4450331552693,436.3879540968705,340.7495159069064,442.1920779147474,534.4142671193669,19.89441005557222,206.6577352851099,492.4427511771748,241.7735300594523,382.6085934358003,376.0863140563925,306.6293313390505]
[368.0682926594546,457.2045927636358,359.1841462238203,464.7078109487218,561.0990701509306,27.17952816676697,221.2817047541209,517.4117655437504,256.4903025712858,402.0961281476057,394.804951938705,322.3432439889111]
[104.9805590746965,131.3527386112043,104.2011355720695,138.6804496432297,177.348356252559,9.001239090243104,70.67352420990476,166.9411671806375,79.89308311196012,122.4161912004151,115.6650356864296,91.94797329425062]
[3.386469647570856,4.69116923611444,3.361326953937725,4.622681654774324,5.720914717824484,0.3000413030081034,2.279791103545315,5.385198941310887,2.663102770398671,3.948909393561777,3.855501189547655,2.966063654653246]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Edit your question to share the input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Traverse the _array_.

Comment: Here is the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

So you have done the right this. All you need is to get all values from `JSONArray`, convert them separately and build an array of `String`.

```java
public static String toString(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, jsonArray.length())
            .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%.2f", (BigDecimal) jsonArray.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
}
```

Finally you snippet could look like this:

```java
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("ac_annual"));
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("solrad_annual"));
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", output.get("outputs").get("capacity_factor"));
System.out.println(toString(output.get("outputs").get("ac_monthly")));
System.out.println(toString(output.get("outputs").get("dc_monthly")));
System.out.println(toString(output.get("outputs").get("poa_monthly")));
System.out.println(toString(output.get("outputs").get("solrad_monthly")));
```

Comment: it's saying: Cannot resolve method 'length' in 'JSONArray'

Comment: What `JSONArray` do you use? Could you give me the full name?

Comment: also, when I add toString() method it's saying that required type is JSONArray, not Float

Comment: Sure, I can see in debug - this is `BigDecimal`

Comment: added the whole code now up here. Not sure where could I see type od JSONarray

Comment: also, I switched length() with the size() function. Hope it's working the same.

Comment: Float was my fault. Accidentally switched BigDecimal and Float in a hope to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your time.
This is solution to my problem:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = null;

        try {
            response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(response.body());
        System.out.println();

        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(response.body());

        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> output = (Map) obj;

        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", ((Double) output.get("outputs").get("ac_annual")));
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", ((Double) output.get("outputs").get("solrad_annual")));
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", ((Double) output.get("outputs").get("capacity_factor")));

        JSONArray acMonthlyArray = (JSONArray) output.get("outputs").get("ac_monthly");
        System.out.println(toString(acMonthlyArray));
        JSONArray dcMonthlyArray = (JSONArray) output.get("outputs").get("dc_monthly");
        System.out.println(toString(dcMonthlyArray));
        JSONArray poaMonthly = (JSONArray) output.get("outputs").get("poa_monthly");
        System.out.println(toString(poaMonthly));
        JSONArray solrad_monthly = (JSONArray) output.get("outputs").get("solrad_monthly");
        System.out.println(toString(solrad_monthly));
    }

    public static String toString(JSONArray array) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(array.get(i).toString());
            result.append(String.format("%.2f", value));

            if (i < array.size() - 1) {
                result.append(", ");
            }
        }

        result.append("]");
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```